# bash_completion not working (for some commands)

Tags: bash, debian

I have new installation of Debian Wheezy, and I have noticed `bash_completion` does not work for some commands. For example, it works for `ping`, but not for `host` (both `ping` and `host` should complete hostnames from `/etc/hosts`).

Further, I have noticed that unlike previous version of Debian (Squeeze), the bash completion settings are no longer stored as separate files in `/etc/bash_completion.d`, but rather as one file in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`. Looks like the infrastructure has been changed.

How to make `bash_completion` work for the `host`  command?

Comment: There is now a `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` instead, `/etc/bash_completion.d` is for overriding default behaviour in `/usr`. There is a `host` file in there (which symlinks to `nslookup`). I find the completion language evil, so I can't help you there!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have installed `nslookup`, but `bash_completion` does not work for `nslookup` either.

Comment: Try `. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/host`

Comment: sourcing `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/host` does not make any difference

Comment: I just noticed that completion works fine for command `dig`, even though there is no file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/dig` or `/etc/bash_completion.d/dig`. How can that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running CentOS 5.6 with bash-completion version 1.3.  After comparing my /etc/bash_completion with Debian's version 2.0, I may have your solution.  I am unable to test this on Debian so YMMV.

Find the commented _known_hosts_real line in /etc/bash_completion (code snippet below is from the Debian file).
Add *host* to the list of commands following the *complete -F* on the next line.
Then *source /etc/bash_completion*.
This works on my system.  You can display the bindings by using the *complete -p* command.

} # _known_hosts_real()
complete -F _known_hosts traceroute traceroute6 tracepath tracepath6 \
     fping fping6 telnet rsh rlogin ftp dig mtr ssh-installkeys showmount

I found the binding information here:  http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1.